# Getting close price for multiple stocks with nested loop in Python

Tags: python, stock

I try to obtain a database with close prices for MSFT and GOOG together. My code works only if I remove one stock. Could someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

start_date = '2014-01-01'
end_date = '2018-01-01'

data1 =('GOOG', 'MSFT')
data2 = data.DataReader(data1, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
data3 = data2.tail(200)

close = data3['Close']
for stock in data1:
    for close_price in close : 
         print(close_price)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Is it a print error or is it a code exception? Could you post a sample of the data2?

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])


names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()
names
```

Result:

```
           ticker        Open   Adj Close
Date                                     
2019-02-01    MMM  201.490005  190.939163
2019-02-04    MMM  199.009995  191.945831
2019-02-05    MMM  200.720001  192.818268
2019-02-06    MMM  201.220001  194.208420
2019-02-07    MMM  201.020004  191.591080
          ...         ...         ...
2020-01-27   ATVI   58.189999   58.320000
2020-01-28   ATVI   58.790001   60.029999
2020-01-29   ATVI   60.490002   60.400002
2020-01-30   ATVI   59.919998   60.889999
2020-01-31   ATVI   60.200001   58.480000
```

Now, if you want the results transposed, horizontal, instead of vertical, add this:

```
df = pd.concat(price_data)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
table
```

Result:

```
ticker           ATVI         MMM  
Date                               
2019-02-01  45.643345  190.939163  
2019-02-04  46.407211  191.945831  
2019-02-05  47.458763  192.818268  
2019-02-06  42.657333  194.208420  
2019-02-07  43.609684  191.591080  
              ...         ...  
2020-01-27  58.320000  174.053833  
2020-01-28  60.029999  164.094025  
2020-01-29  60.400002  160.546158  
2020-01-30  60.889999  161.051575  
2020-01-31  58.480000  157.236130
```

Comment: I kept getting "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" when I tried table = df.pivot(columns='ticker') from the code snippet above. However changing it to this solved my problem -> table = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='ticker', values=['Adj Close'], aggfunc='first').

Comment: You probably have two tickers that are exactly the same. Make sure you don't have any duplicate tickers. See the link below for more info.

https://github.com/ash-wicus-ml/Notebooks/blob/master/Optimization%20-%20Portfolio%20Optimization.ipynb

Comment: ASH thanks, after looking at the complete code, I realized what I was doing wrong and now it worked butter smooth. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@user12679236 , you can just call the data frame `close` to print it or if you want to iterate over a data frame you need to know the length and slice it. Here the for loop

```
for i in range(0,close['GOOG'].count()):
    print(close[i:i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read data from Yahoo!, but this doesn't work anymore (I am unable to load any data with your code):

https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew.html#v0-6-0-january-24-2018

> v0.6.0 (January 24, 2018)
>
> This is a major release from 0.5.0. We recommend that all users
>   upgrade.
>
> Warning
>
> Yahoo!, Google Options, Google Quotes and EDGAR have been immediately
>   deprecated.

The list of current supported data sources can be found here:

https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown us here. it seems to me that the logic of your code is not dependent on the stocks themselves, hence the data you get in `data3` simply does not contain the data for one of the companies you want to track.

In the code below you are looping through the same data (`close`) twice without any condition to match it to the stocks as data3 is just a `.tail()` subset of `data2`.

```
data2 = data.DataReader(data1, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
data3 = data2.tail(200)
close = data3['Close']
for stock in data1:
    for close_price in close : 
         print(close_price)
```

you would instead want to first create a close for each of the stocks:

```
close = {}
for stock in data1:
    # a filter method stub that has to be implemented based on your data
    close[stock] = filter_data2_by_stock(stock)
```

by filtering data by the stock you would be sure to get the stock that you are looking for instead of whatever comes in the tail of your `data2` dataset.

you would then loop through this filtered data to get the close values for your stock as

```
for stock in data1:
    for close_price in close[stock] : 
         print(close_price)
```